# Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded set and $\alpha \in (0,1)$ such that: $\mu^*(A\cap Q)≤\alpha\cdot\mu(Q)$. Show that A is the null set.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

> Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded set and $\alpha \in (0,1)$ such that for all cuboids $Q\subset\mathbb{R}^n$: $$\mu^*(A\cap Q)≤\alpha\cdot\mu(Q)$$ Show that A is the null set.

How to begin? What conclusions can I draw from A being bounded?

Comment: You can always reduce to the case "$A$ bounded", so this hypothesis is superfluous.

Comment: It doesn't seem too hard to show that the measure of $A$ is zero. Proving that it's empty however has me stumped for the moment.

Comment: @SimonS A null set does not necessarily be empty, does it? We defined a null set simply to have a measure of zero although it may contain an infinite amount of elements.

Comment: A null set by any other name would smell as...got it. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{ Q_n \}$ be a countable cover for $A$, then

$\mu^*(A) = \mu^*(\bigcup_n Q_n \cap A) \leq \sum_n \mu^*(Q_n \cap A) \leq \alpha \sum_n \mu(Q_n)$.

Now use the definition of $\mu^*(A) = \inf \left\{ \sum_i \mu(Q_i) \ | \ A \subset \bigcup_i Q_i \right\}$.

Comment: I editted your post to add * to indicate the outer Lebesgue measure. However, I still don't know where to go from here. How can I show that the $inf$ is 0?

Comment: What is $\inf \left\{ \alpha \sum_n \mu(Q_n) \right\}$ equal to?

Comment: If $Q_n$ is the arbitrary cover you defined, it should be equal to $\alpha\cdot\mu^*(A)$.

Comment: Yes and hence ... look again at the top inequality, $\mu^*(A) \leq \alpha \sum_n \mu(Q_n)$ ...

Comment: Mm... obviously $\alpha\mu^*(A) < \mu^*(A) ≤ \alpha\sum_n\mu(Q_n)$ but that's not of any use. - Just saw your edit, give me a second.

Comment: Oh well: Actually we have that $\mu^*(A) < \alpha\mu^*(A) ≤ \alpha\sum_n\mu(Q_n)$ since $\alpha\mu^*(A)$ is the greatest lower bound. However since $\alpha \neq 0$ we have that $A$ must be a null set. Is that correct?

Comment: As $\mu^*(A) \leq \alpha \sum_n \mu(Q_n)$ for all covers $\{ Q_n \}$, it follows from basic properties of real numbers that $\mu^*(A) \leq \inf \{ \alpha \sum_n \mu(Q_n) \}$. But this last term is just $\alpha  \inf \{ \sum_n \mu(Q_n) \} = \alpha \mu^*(A)$. Hence $\mu^*(A) \leq \alpha \mu^*(A)$ for some constant $0 < \alpha < 1$. It follows that $\mu^*(A)$ must equal zero.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant with my last comment, if it wasn't clear. Thank you for your help and patience, Simon.

Comment: Great. I know when I first learnt this stuff it took me a while to get used to it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\beta< 1 $ a bit larger than $\alpha$.

Let's first agree on this: for every box $Q$ there exists a countable family of boxes $(Q_i)$ inside $Q$ that cover $Q\cap A$ and such that 
$$\sum \mu(Q_i) \le \beta\cdot \mu(Q)$$
Repeat this procedure several times ($N$ times) to get a countable family of boxes covering $Q\cap A$ with sum of volumes $\le \beta^N \cdot \mu(Q)$.